# Don't allow ajax url to submit if validation false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 text boxes in a form.I don't want to allow ajax url to submit if any of the validation is false.How can i achieve this.I dont know much about jquery. Please help.

```
<div class="coupon" style="display:none;">                              
    <input type="text" class="coupon-name" name="fullname"  id="fullname">
    <span class="name-error"></span>
    <input type="text" class="coupon-email" name="email" id="email">
    <span class="email-error"></span>
    <button type="submit" value="status_add" name="status_add" id="add-status"    onclick="checkStatus()">Apply</button>
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkStatus(){
        var fullname = $(".coupon-name").val();
        var email = $(".coupon-email").val();

        if(fullname == ''){
            $('input[name="fullname"]').next('span').text('Please Enter Your Name');
        }
        if(email == ''){
            $('input[name="email"]').next('span').text('Please Enter a Email Id');
        }                               

        $.ajax(
        {
            url     : "<?php echo base_url('myaccount/validate/'); ?>",
            type    : "POST",
            data    : {fullname: fullname,email:email} ,
```

Comment: `if(fullname && email) { $.ajax(...); }`

Comment: add return false inside if condition if(fullname == ''){
            $('input[name="fullname"]').next('span').text('Please Enter Your Name');   return false;
        }

Comment: `if(fullname == ''){ your code;
            return false;
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did not spend much time on you're code, don't know if there are any other errors, but may you should put the ajax part in a "else" condition, otherwise it will be done everytime, independent of the result of the two if-conditions.

Comment: In ajax, I am checking for validation and other conditions.But Firstly, I want that none of the text boxes should be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Use `return false;`

```
var fullname = $(".coupon-name").val();
        var email = $(".coupon-email").val();
        var error=0;
        if(fullname == ''){
            $('input[name="fullname"]').next('span').text('Please Enter Your Name');
         error=1;
        }
        if(email == ''){
            $('input[name="email"]').next('span').text('Please Enter a Email Id');
         error=1;
        } 

       if(error>0){
         return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the boolean flag in the checkStatus.

```
function checkStatus(){
    var fullname = $(".coupon-name").val();
    var email = $(".coupon-email").val();

    var isValidate = true;

    if(fullname == ''){
        isValidate = false;
        $('input[name="fullname"]').next('span').text('Please Enter ..');
    }
    if(email == ''){
        isValidate = false;
        $('input[name="email"]').next('span').text('Please Enter a Email');
    }                               

    if (!isValidate) { return;}

    //ajax request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  use this:`<input type="button" />`

and `<form id="form" method="post" action="xxxxx.php">`

if you js code ok then do this:`$('#form').submit();`